# ReactJS get token string from API fetch

Tags: javascript, string, reactjs, api, jwt

I set up an API in Java. But now I'm developping a client in ReactJS. The authentication uses a JWT Token. With Postman, when I send a POST request to the authentication URL, it returns me a JWT token like this :

`eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZHVzZXIiOjEsImlzcyI6ImF1dGgwIn0.0BXAQl-yMIDeAU6Emppo6LBIm1RAdLa9vDWbQkdLs1o`

That's exactly what I want. But I don't know how to retrieve a string after a fetch call in ReactJS.

I tried to use the promises and wrote this :

```
.then((data) => {
    data.text().then((token) => {
        alert(token)
    })
})
```

But it returns me nothing, I have an alert with no text.
How to get String from the Object Response returned by the fetch ?

Comment: why not make another fetch call

Comment: Because it already returns me what I want I think, but I don't know how to get this as a string

Comment: What's the value of `data`?

Comment: `Response { type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:8080/projet_p52/Signin/apiSignin/signin", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, bodyUsed: false } `

Comment: That token is likely stored on `data.headers.Authorization` or some other header field. In your `then()` method callback add a `console.log(data.headers);` and look at the value.

Comment: When I do `console.log(data.headers)`, it shows me an empty array called Headers

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you back end server return `Content-Type=application/json`? Instead `text()` method try using `json()`.

Try this:

```
fetch('/next/page')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(text) { 
    // <!DOCTYPE ....
    console.log(text); 
  });
```

Comment: No my server produces text plain

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and was able to get the token with this:

```
.then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
    let token = res.token;
    console.log("token: ", token);
});
```

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body

Answer (score 0):

The text() method on that response object is what you are looking for.

Using `await` syntax I think is a bit simpler than using `then()` With await, `this` in `this.setState()` is scoped as expected.

```
async getStrResponse() {
  const response = await fetch('myController/GetStringTest');
  const stringResponse = await response.text();
  this.setState({ someStr: stringResponse, loading: false });
}
```